# ClassNotFoundException with Grails Spock Plugin

Tags: plugins, grails, spock

I have a Grails 1.3.7 project and but when I installed the Grails Spock Plugin: I got this:

```
    Installed plugin spock-0.5-groovy-1.7 to location /Users/tiffany/.grails/1.3.7/projects/grails-with-spock/plugins/spock-0.5-groovy-1.7. ...
Resolving plugin JAR dependencies ...
[Fatal Error] settings.xml:19:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
WARNING: Dependencies cannot be resolved for plugin [spock] due to error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
Executing spock-0.5-groovy-1.7 plugin post-install script ...
Plugin spock-0.5-groovy-1.7 installed
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/tiffany/Workspace/chrome-webstore/grails-with-spock/target/classes
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/tiffany/.grails/1.3.7/projects/grails-with-spock/plugin-classes
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/tiffany/.grails/1.3.7/projects/grails-with-spock/resources
```

And when I tried running a simple domain UnitSpec, I got this stack trace:

```
[Fatal Error] settings.xml:19:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
WARNING: Dependencies cannot be resolved for plugin [spock] due to error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1284ms.
Running script /Users/tiffany/dev/grails/scripts/TestApp.groovy
Environment set to test
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/tiffany/.grails/1.3.7/projects/grails-with-spock/plugin-classes
  [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/tiffany/.grails/1.3.7/projects/grails-with-spock/plugin-classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/tiffany/Workspace/chrome-webstore/grails-with-spock/target/classes
  [groovyc] Compiling 7 source files to /Users/tiffany/Workspace/chrome-webstore/grails-with-spock/target/classes
Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java_lang_ClassLoader$loadClass.call(Unknown Source)
    at _Events$_run_closure1_closure5.doCall(_Events.groovy:18)
    at _Events$_run_closure1.doCall(_Events.groovy:24)
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy:30)
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy)
    at _Events$_run_closure3.doCall(_Events.groovy:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener$targetStarted.call(Unknown Source)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    ... 10 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.spock.test.GrailsSpecTestType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java_lang_ClassLoader$loadClass.call(Unknown Source)
    at _Events$_run_closure1_closure5.doCall(_Events.groovy:18)
    at _Events$_run_closure1.doCall(_Events.groovy:24)
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy:30)
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy)
    at _Events$_run_closure3.doCall(_Events.groovy:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener$targetStarted.call(Unknown Source)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? And if so, how do I resolve this? I've tried googling but I got nothing >.<

I also tried creating a new Grails app and only installed the Spock Plugin, nothing else. I got the exact same result.

Comment: which version are you trying to install?! 0.4 or 0.5! I tried both here in a empty project and it works !!

Comment: I installed version 0.5-groovy-1.7

Comment: btw, what grails version did you use? it doesn't work with my grails 1.3.7 >.<

Comment: I used grails1.3.7 also .. and it worked fine! try running "grails plugin-list" and see if the plugin is bellow installed!

Comment: Since others have confirmed that things work in an empty project, start with an empty project and make sure it works for you.  If not, the problem is your environment.  If so, it's a problem specific to your project, and your best best is to gradually examine the differences between the empty project and yours...

Answer (score 4):

Many of these problems can be solved with a simple `grails clean` or if even that does not help try to delete the `.grails` folder in your user directory and run the plugin installation again.

Comment: Deleting the entire %USER_PROFILE%/.grails folder was a bit much, just take out the %USER_PROFILE%/.grails/<grails version> folder, that way you do not have to redownload all of your dependencies into the ivy-cache folder when you build the app